# Unable to load chrome default profile in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/bhanu/Downloads/chromedriver");

String profilePath = "/home/user_name/.config/google-chrome/Default/Default";

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir="+profilePath);
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I am using Ubuntu, and not able to load my default profile . Everytime when i run my code selenium is opening a browser with selenium profile.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `addArguments`, it needs to match exactly what you'd pass into the actual binary.

change `user-data-dir=` to `--user-data-dir=` and `start-maximized` to `--start-maximized`